# Pass data to custom pipe from component in angular 2

Tags: pipe, angular

How can I pass data to custom pipe from the component?
I am trying to bind the form data to the component and pass to the pipe.

`<input [(ngModel)]="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">`

want to pass 'this.phone' to 'PhoneNum' pipe from the component.

This is done in template.
`{{phoneNumber | PhoneNum}} // PhoneNum is the pipe`

My question is done in AngularJS in this way from the controller

`<input ng-model="phone placeholder="Phone Number">`
`$filter(‘PhoneNum’)($scope.phone); // something like this.`
Appreciate the Time!

Answer (score 5):

Since a pipe is just a class that implements the `PipeTransform` interface, you can register it with the component's injector through the providers property:

```
import { MyPipe } from './my.pipe.ts';

@Component({
   ...
   providers:[MyPipe]
})
```

Then you can inject the Pipe into any component's (or child component's) constructor through DI and use it by calling the transform method:

```
export class MyComponent {
   private filteredData:Data[];
   constructor(private mypipe:MyPipe) {
       var data = [...];
       this.filteredData = this.mypipe.transform(data, []);
   }
};
```

Or if you don't want to register it through DI, you can just instantiate the Pipe when you need it:

```
export class MyComponent {
   private filteredData:Data[];
   constructor() {
       var data = [...];
       this.filteredData = new MyPipe().transform(data, []);
   }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do that with two-way data binding, but you can break it into two one-way bindings and filter one of them through your pipe:

`<input [ngModel]="phone" (ngModelChange)="phone = PhoneNum.transform($event)">`

or you can leave the original propery just the way it is and call the pipe in the getter of the property:

template:

`<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="phone">`

component:

```
private _phone:string = 'test';

public get phone(){ return this.PhoneNum.transform(this._phone); }

public set phone(phone){ this._phone = phone; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Double binding with pipes will not work, you can use one way binding and ngModelChange for update:

```html
<input [ngModel]="phone | PhoneNum" (ngModelChange)="phone = $event">
```

Comment: This is the only solution that works with angular 2.1.2 Only thing to note is that there's an extra parenthesis that shouldn't be there (can't edit just one character)

Answer (score 0):

For me, using only the following solution didn't work:

```
<input [ngModel]="phone | PhoneNum" (ngModelChange)="phone = $event">
```

The problem: The assignment of phone = $event didn't work for all cases until user had to focus out the input element.

So I suggest using **ALSO** ElementRef Object for handling the native input element:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="points" #points maxlength="8" [(ngModel)]="range" (ngModelChange)="range=saverange($event, points)">
```

**Component:**

```
    onChangeAchievement(eventStr: string, eRef): string {

      //Do something (some manipulations) on input and than return it to be saved:

       //In case you need to force of modifing the Element-Reference value on-focus of input:
       var eventStrToReplace = eventStr.replace(/[^0-9,eE\.\+]+/g, "");
       if (eventStr != eventStrToReplace) {
           eRef.value = eventStrToReplace;
       }

      return this.getNumberOnChange(eventStr);

    }
```

The idea here:

1. Letting the "(ngModelChange)" method to do  the Setter job:

   (ngModelChange)="range=saverange($event, points)"
2. Enabling direct access to the native Dom element using this call:

   eRef.value = eventStrToReplace;